# Regex for any character except quote after comma

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match every word separated by comma, but it must not include a quote like `'` or `"`.

I was using this regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9][\!\[\@\\\:\;a-zA-Z0-9`_\s,]+[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

However, it only matches a character and number and not a symbol.

The output should be:

```
example,example //true
exaplle,examp@3 //true, with symbol or number
example, //false, because there is no word after comma
,example //false, because there is no word before comma
@#example&$123,&example& //true, with all character and symbol except quote
```

Comment: do you want the whole string to match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the whole string to match perfectly with your conditions and return true then and then only.

These are the conditions-

- Each word should be separated by a comma, said comma should have 2 valid words on each side
- Words can contain anything except the 2 kinds of quotes (`'` and `"`) and whitespace characters (spaces and newlines).

The regex you would use is this- `^(?:[^,'"\s]+,[^,'"\s]+)+$`, with the global flag (`g`) on.

Check out the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/8IegTs/1)

Edit: As per request of being able to match only a single word.

This is the regex you would use for that- `^(?:(?:[^,'"\s]+,[^,'"\s]+)+|[^,'"\s]+)$`

This will match words separated by a `,` as well as match just a single word.

The conditions for what qualifies as a word remains the same as aforementioned.

Quick explanation:-

- `^[^,'"\s]+,[^,'"\s]+$`

  This part matches 2 words separated by a comma, `[^,'"\s]+` denotes a word
- Wrapping that whole thing in `^(?:[^,'"\s]+,[^,'"\s]+)+$` simply makes it repeat, so it'll match N number of words separated by a comma, not just 2
- Then adding another alternative using `|` and wrapping the whole thing in a group (non-capturing), we get `^(?:(?:[^,'"\s]+,[^,'"\s]+)+|[^,'"\s]+)$`

  This simply just adds the alternative `[^,'"\s]+` - which matches a singular word.

Check out the updated demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/AV1sci/1/)

Comment: what if the condition were only 1 word

Comment: @TunkuSalim Added the solution for that too

Answer (score 5):

You can match 1+ times what is present in the character class. Then repeat 1+ times in a non capturing group `(?:` what is present in the character class, preceded by a comma.

```
^[!\[@\\:;a-zA-Z0-9`_ &$#]+(?:,[!\[@\\:;a-zA-Z0-9`_ &$#]+)+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ldZsOJ/1)

Note that you don't have to escape `\!`, `\@`, `\:` and `\;` in the character class, and that `\s` might also possibly match a newline.